# Sorted Sequential Search

Tags: python, sequential

Hi so the goal here is to improve the number of steps needed to find an element in a list using `Sequential Search`.

So I have an unsorted List `numbers = [5, 2, 1, 0, 3]` and i'm trying to find lets say element `3`. It takes `5 steps` to find it.

My task here is to create a new function called `sortedSequentialSearch()` that takes in a sorted list in ascending order and improve it to reduce the steps needed to find element `3`.

Here's my code for the normal Sequential Search:

```
def sequentialSearch(theValues, target):
    n = len(theValues)
    count = 0 

    for i in range(n):
        count = count + 1
        if theValues[i] == target:
            print(f"Found, {count} steps needed")
            return True
    return False
```

How can I improve this if I lets say pass in `numbers.sort()` ?

Comment: You can try the binary search. It will reduce searching time to `log(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary search after sorting the array. It has log(n) time complexity.

In this case 2.3 steps, which is better than 3.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way to search a sorted array is binary search.  I modified your code to use it:

```py
def binary_search(theValues, target, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    middle = (upper_bound + lower_bound) // 2

    if theValues[middle] == target:
        return True
    elif upper_bound <= lower_bound:
        return False
    elif target > theValues[middle]:
        return binary_search(theValues, target, middle + 1, upper_bound)
    else:
        return binary_search(theValues, target, lower_bound, middle - 1)
```

Another option is [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search).  This algorithm is more efficient than binary search if the numbers are uniformly distributed, averaging `log(log(n))` time. It's worst case isn't as good though, because it can take `O(n)` time if the numbers change exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are sorted you do not have to continue the search once you have reached an element greater than the value of the element you are trying to find

```
def sequentialSearch(theValues, target):
  n = len(theValues)
  count = 0 

  for i in range(n):
    count = count + 1
    if theValues[i] == target:
        print(f"Found, {count} steps needed")
        return True
    if theValues[i] > target:
        return False
  return False
```